# Undefined function 'Replace' in expression. Run-time error 3085

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2010

I'm working with a vb 6.0 application. There I'm using a replace function in my query. The query works fine in access but when it runs in vb it gives me the error:

> "Undefined function 'Replace' in expression. Run-time error 3085".

I think that I'm missing references. I currently added following references.

[image: References]

The 'Replace' is located in the where clause:

> `...WHERE ((DateValue(Replace(Invoice.InvoiceDate, ': ', ' '))
>   Between...`

The following full query is giving me the error.

```
Set DrsInv = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Invoice.InvoiceDate, InvoicedProduct.InvoiceType, Invoice.InvoiceStatus, Invoice.RetailerID, Invoice.DailySalesID, Invoice.RepID, InvoicedProduct.Quantity, InvoicedProduct.UnitRate, InvoicedProduct.TotalItemValue From Invoice INNER JOIN InvoicedProduct ON (Invoice.DailySalesID = InvoicedProduct.DailySalesID) AND (Invoice.RepID = InvoicedProduct.RepID) AND (Invoice.InvoiceID = InvoicedProduct.InvoiceID)" _
                            & " WHERE ((DateValue(Replace(Invoice.InvoiceDate, ': ', ' ')) Between #" & Format(dtpFrom.value, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "# And #" & Format(dtpTo.value, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#) AND (InvoicedProduct.ProductID = '" & Srs("ProductID") & "'))" _
                            & " GROUP BY Invoice.InvoiceDate, InvoicedProduct.InvoiceType, Invoice.InvoiceStatus, Invoice.RetailerID, Invoice.DailySalesID, Invoice.RepID, InvoicedProduct.Quantity, InvoicedProduct.UnitRate, InvoicedProduct.TotalItemValue HAVING ((InvoicedProduct.InvoiceType)='Invoice' AND (Invoice.InvoiceStatus)='VALID') Order By Invoice.InvoiceDate DESC")
```

I use the replace function because InvoiceDate is a text feild. So it is giving me the error "Data type mismatch", when I try to convert it to a date field in query. The colon inside the date is the reason for this error. That's why I need to replace the colon. I could not be able to change the database field. So this is the solution as the way I see it.

The data of the field InvoiceDate looks like following

[image]
[image]

Comment: Replace belongs to _Visual Basic for Applications_. Latest DLL is _VBE7.DLL_.

Comment: How did you define `db`? Please add the code with initialization too

Comment: Looks like the problem is `Replace` isn't recognized by the database engine. I couldn't replicate it, but I do know `Replace` is at an odd place, where it is a standard function, but isn't allowed in default values, for example.

Comment: The Jet Expression Service doesn't implement Replace, InStrRev, or several other newer functions.  MS Access uses a proprietary scheme to inject its own VBA processor in its place but VB6 programs can't do that.

Comment: TSion Sir I use "Dim db As Database". Should I use ADODB or DAO. Like Dim db As ADODB Database.  Gustav, do I need to get the latest dll.

Comment: I tried Dim db As DAO.Database. But the same error

Comment: I think Bob nailed it

Comment: Why do you even need to do this Replace() in the first place?

Comment: Can you just build the format you want from the InvoiceDate field by using lefts, rights, etc and concatenating them together?  It would help to see what some examples of InvoiceDate values look like in your system.

Comment: This is the same reason that a VB6 program cannot use "user defined functions" in a Jet query expression.  I've never found a workaround.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908724), from someone who is having the same problem in C#, has some ideas that may be of some use.

Comment: I edited the question mentioning why I use replace function.

Comment: Luke G. Sir, I have to try it. but I'm no expert. But it's worth to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't make much sense to me. As the commenters have asked can you explain why you need to remove the ":" from InvoiceDate? As @LukeG says - adding data examples would help us.

By removing the ":" from the time AM/PM part of the date, your function will fail even if the Replace worked, because you'd be asking DateValue to convert as string that is now not formatted as a proper date

There's a couple things you can do:

**EDITED:**

*Since we now know InvoiceDate is NOT a Date Field you can just remove the time part of the field by taking the first 10 characters and converting to date:*

```
(CDate(Left(Invoice.InvoiceDate,10)) Between #" & Format(dtpFrom.value, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "# And #" & Format(dtpTo.value, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#)
```

Comment: It is my bad not giving the all info of my question sir. The InvoiceDate is not a Date field. And therefore it need to convert and the second answer is giving me the error data type mismatch

Comment: I added data samples of InvoiceDate Field in my edited question

Comment: Okay - changed the solution to match the fact it is not a date field. Just strip time from the full field before comparing